# Whitespace in header value while using curl in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am getting the following error

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: someToken"

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST_URL='http://google.com'

AUTH_TOKEN='someToken'

#echo $payload
payload='{}'
authHeader='"Authorization:Bearer '$AUTH_TOKEN'"'
curlcmd='curl -X POST '$HOST_URL' --data ''"'$payload'"''  -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -H  '$authHeader
echo $curlcmd
echo $($curlcmd)
```

But when I run the exact line which is outputted in $curlcmd , it runs fine directly on terminal

```
curl -X POST http://google.com --data "{}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer someToken"
```

I think its due to the whitespace between the "Bearer" and "someToken" , do we need to escape?

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050  and https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 4):

The general rule of thumb in `bash` is don't ever try to use a variable as a placeholder to store your commands and then run your command from it. This is covered in detail in [BashFAQ/50 - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

As more quotes come into usage, your command will be made difficult to maintain. The simplest solution would be to use arrays. For your case though, careful nesting will solve the problem.

```
payload='{}'
hostURL='http://google.com'
authToken='someToken'
authHeader='Authorization:Bearer "'"$authToken"'"'
```

now that variables are define, define an array to store your command args

```
curlCMD=(-X POST "$hostURL" --data "$payload" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "$authHeader")
```

and now do a proper quoted expansion

```
curl "${curlCMD[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
curl -X POST $hostURL --data $payload -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer '${authToken}''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see what commands are being executed in a script, you can
use `set -x`.

Example:

```
$ set -x; echo a; echo b; echo c
+ echo a
a
+ echo b
b
+ echo c
c
```

Using the original code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -x

HOST_URL='http://google.com'
AUTH_TOKEN='someToken'

payload='{}'
authHeader="Authorization:Bearer '$AUTH_TOKEN'"
curl -X POST "$HOST_URL" --data "$payload" -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
  -H "$authHeader"
```

Or, if you want to see only parts of a script, you can wrap them in a subshell
with `set -x` inside of it:

```
$ echo a; ( set -x; echo b ); echo c
a
+ echo b
b
c
```

With your script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
HOST_URL='http://google.com'
AUTH_TOKEN='someToken'

(
set -x
payload='{}'
authHeader="Authorization:Bearer '$AUTH_TOKEN'"
curl -X POST "$HOST_URL" --data "$payload" -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
  -H "$authHeader"
)
```